# What could be a mechanical model of repelling same-signed charges?

Tags: electrostatics, simulations

Interaction between multiple gravitating masses can easily be modeled by using an elastic membrane with several balls on it (like in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MTY1Kje0yLg)). But this is the case where same-signed "charges" attract. Is there a similarly simple mechanical model where same-signed charges would repel and opposite ones would attract, as do electric charges?

Comment: Think of it in terms of two individuals play catch with virtual baseballs. Conservation of momentum would lead to repulsion for like charged individuals. Don't know how to get attraction from unlike charges however.

Comment: I can't think of a way off hand.  The reason the gravitating mass video works is because you are modeling an attractive force, and you have an attractive force pulling down on the balls and membrane.  You would almost certainly have to use something other than gravity pulling down to model it.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably several ways to do this (form a 2D model of a 3D force in general).

For opposite charges, one is the idea behind the "XY-model": imagine that you've got a 2D surface and at every point you've got an arrow pointing in some direction in the surface. These arrows interact with their nearest neighbors in a way that reduces energy if they "line up", and they interact with your "charges" in a way that the charge's nearest neighbors want to "spin around it" either clockwise or counterclockwise, locally. Clockwise will be positive charge; counterclockwise will be negative charge. Call this surface the "spin-sheet" for short, and the arrows on it "spins".

Now as you move your vortices around in the spin-sheet, you need to put energy in twisting around nearest neighbors against this intrinsic desire to line-up. So the vortices are changing the energy in the spin sheet and we can imagine that we get that energy from the kinetic energy of the particles, so energy is conserved. But this also means that this energy transfer appears like a force on the particles.

This force will tend to repel like particles because when they get near each other their boundaries "collide"; they go opposite ways and the spin-sheet does not like it when neighboring spins oppose. It will tend to attract opposite particles because their boundaries "cooperate"; they both go the same way and so the sheet is lower energy when they get nearer to each other. Finally when two of these particles get together there may be some complicated fields near them, but the fact that their "net vorticity" sums to 0 is reflected in the spins all having a constant orientation far away from the interactions of the particles.

Comment: This looks more like a description of a numerical simulation to me, than of a mechanical model. E.g. I don't have an idea how I would achieve this tendency to align, how I would realize the force from the field to the particles etc. in an experimental setup.

Comment: I mean, typically the XY model is taken to model electron spins or the like, though keeping those in-the-plane might be difficult. You'd probably want to affix magnets to pivots, kind of like how compasses work.